# Angular 2 Input ngFor not updating only 1 input value

Tags: angular

Here's the code, i'm looping over unit names and displaying their value.
 [image]

Notice that I print out the same value that is binded to my input.

Here is what is being shown.
[image]

It only doesn't update that one value.. Everytime I change these input it updates all value but one.  I've tried changeDetectionRef, [ngModel], binding it to {{u}}.  Can't get anything to fix the issue.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use two way data binding `[(ngModel)]`:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let u of unitCache">
  <input [(ngModel)]="u">
</ng-container>
```

fyi:

Don't use screenshots from your code, paste your actual code

Comment: That doesn't work, get the error -> Cannot assign to a reference or variable!